# Creating a 2D image gallery (Horizontal + Vertical) in C#

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I am currently working on a project for a fashion store app for Windows Phone. For the catalogue I need to create an image gallery in which if you scroll vertically you see images related to the same product, and if you scroll sideways you will see the next/previous product.

I have started off by creating a little concept gallery which is 3x3 images. One column is planes, the second tanks and the third warships. I used 1 horizontal FlipView which has 3 vertical FlipViews as it's items.

Here is the XAML code:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipBase">
        <FlipView x:Name="a">
            <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
        </FlipView>
        <FlipView x:Name="b">
            <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            </FlipView>
        <FlipView x:Name="c">
            <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
            </FlipView>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

Here is the C# code:
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

```
        //PRIMEIRA COLUMNA
        Image foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/plane/plane_spitfire.jpg"));
        a.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/plane/plane_stuka.jpg"));
        a.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/plane/plane_yak9.jpg"));
        a.Items.Add(foto);

        //SEGUNDA COLUMNA
        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/tank/tank_IS.jpg"));
        b.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/tank/tank_Patton.jpg"));
        b.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/tank/tank_Tiger.jpg"));
        b.Items.Add(foto);

        //TERCEIRA COLUMNA
        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/destroyer/destroyer_german.jpg"));
        c.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/destroyer/destroyer_russian.jpg"));
        c.Items.Add(foto);

        foto = new Image();
        foto.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/destroyer/destroyer_usa.jpg"));
        c.Items.Add(foto);

    }
}
```

I have 2 main questions:
 -Is there better way to do this? (One that will allow me to dynamically add columns and items)
-How can I restrict horizontal movement when vertical movement is detected, and viceversa (to prevent diagonal movement)?

This is my first post here. Thank you very much for your answers!